# How to create a full shape from quarter mesh with adding extra mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

i have a quard mesh design image 1 below. And i want to make it full model all 4 side. For example if i add mirror on all axis it will be a complete model but i have 9 mesh mean time and when i add a new mesh (Its not a single mesh some have boolean and some have array some have solidify modifiers?) i have to add a mirror modifier to it always. Is there any way if i add a mesh it automatically update on all side.

**Quarter Mesh**

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway if i add a mesh it should add in all 3 side

Comment: Its really unclear what you are trying to ask, please edit the question so its easier to understand your issue

Comment: @ViplavPrakash i have a quard mesh design image 1. And i want to make it full model. For example if we add mirror on all axis it will be a complete model but i have 9 mesh mean time and when i add a new mesh i have to add a mirror modifier to it. Is there any way if i have a mesh it automatically update on all side.

Comment: Select all the meshes and press CTRL + J to join the meshes then one mirror modifier will be enough to mirror the whole object